# unable to get valid api key

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when I try to get an API key:

> The fingerprint that you entered is not valid
>   Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.

Comment: changala prashna aahe.mazya kadun +1

Comment: You need to get a valid fingerprint. What fingerprint are you using?

Comment: im using MD5 fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

If you're using debug key use the following command on Windows

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Make sure you get the MD5 fingerprint, not SHA1. If you're using Java 7 the keytool gives the SHA1 fingerprint. To get the MD5 use the -v flag in your keytool command

Comment: ya i did whatever u told but still im facing the same problem

Comment: You're probably using the wrong key, if you're doing everything else correct. But your question is too vague, so any answer is a guess. Google it, there are lots of tutorials and examples. If you have any hope of a future in IT, you should be able to figure this out for yourself